# Get input value after change

Tags: jquery, input, get, set, return-value

Html code:

```
<input type="text" name="iframe_title" value="null" />
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.example.com/somepage.html"></iframe>
<button onclick="steps()">Start !</button>
```

Let's supose that the page http://www.example.com/somepage.html has h1 title **This is a super title**

```
function steps()
{
    $('#iframe').load(function()
    {
        $('[name=iframe_title]').prop('value',$('#iframe').contents().find('body').find('h1').text());
        alert($('[name=iframe_title]').val()) /* RETURNS THE CORRECT TITLE - This is a super title */


        if($('[name=iframe_title]').prop('value') == 'This is a super title')
        {
            alert('Well done !');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('NOT WORKING !');
        }
    })
}
```

The response is NOT WORKING !

I try to use Chrome console with those lines:

```
alert($('[name=iframe_title]').val()); // Returns: This is a super title
alert($('#iframe').contents().find('body').find('h1').text()); // Returns: This is a super title
```

What's wrong here ?

I used inside steps function val(), prop() and attr() to set and get the input value. Nothing. Doesn't work...

PS: Tested on Chrome.

**EDIT:**

It's possible that somepage.html to have content inserted via ajax, but I don't think that this is a problem because after setting the value, I'm using alert immediately and shows me the correct title text.

**SOLVED**: Using .toString() function.

```
if ($('[name=iframe_title]').val().toString() == $('#iframe').contents().find('body').find('h1').text().toString())
{
    alert("It's working now !");
}
```

Comment: Could I know from where `steps()` you're calling?

Comment: There is closing brace `)` missing as well. After the `load` handler `function` close.

Comment: I'm calling steps() onclick. I'm sorry for ). My code seems to be correct. Tested with Chrome javascript console.

Comment: Did you check browser console for errors? What is your page origin (your page domain)?

Comment: Yes, I already check the browser console and there is no error. The page where I have the iframe code is on my domain and the src of iframe is on external domain. BUT the access to external domain is not a problem for me.